# Manipulate data in dictionary-column from TSV

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a TSV file where one of the columns are a dictionary-format type.

Example of headers and one row (notice the string-quotes in Preferences-column)

```
    Name, Age, Preferences
    Nick, 18, "[{"Hobby":"Football", "Food":"Pizza", "FavoriteNumber":"72"}]"
```

To read the file into python:

```
    df = pd.read_csv('search_data_assessment.tsv',delimiter='\t')
```

To remove the strings of the "Preferences" at beginning and end, I used ast.literal_eval:

```
    df["Preferences"] = ast.literal_eval(df["Preferences"])
```

This raises "ValueError: malformed node or string: 0", but it seems to do the trick.

**The question**: How can I check all rows and look for "FavoriteNumber" in Preferences, and if it == 72, change it to 100 (arbitrary example)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.Series.apply` with a custom function. Just note this is bordering on abuse of Pandas. Pandas isn't designed to hold lists of dictionaries in series. Here, you are running a loop in a particularly inefficient way.

```
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.DataFrame([['Nick', 18, '[{"Hobby":"Football", "Food":"Pizza", "FavoriteNumber":"72"}]']],
                  columns=['Name', 'Age', 'Preferences'])

def updater(x):
    if x[0]['FavoriteNumber'] == '72':
        x[0]['FavoriteNumber'] = '100'
    return x

df['Preferences'] = df['Preferences'].apply(literal_eval)
df['Preferences'] = df['Preferences'].apply(updater)

print(df['Preferences'].iloc[0])

[{'Hobby': 'Football', 'Food': 'Pizza', 'FavoriteNumber': '100'}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. The file I'm working on is quite large (72MB containing 70.000 rows). Should I avoid using Pandas for this task?

Comment: You might be OK with 72MB. Test it and see if it works for you. If you have a larger dataset, you may wish to consider alternatives (probably ask another question focusing on performance).